# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. Unrecognized option: --module-path

Tags: javafx, javafx-17

I tried to run my application of JavaFx using MVC

C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Practica_Arqui\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1342: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Practica_Arqui\nbproject\build-impl.xml:969: Java returned: 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your question "javafx-17", but you are not using a compatible JDK. Likely you are using Java 8 (which does not have a module path).

Ensure that you have only java JDK 17 (not just JavaFX 17) installed on your machine and that your development environment is configured to use it.

Also ensure that your development environment, and every other piece of software that you use, is up-to-date, running the latest released stable versions.